# Extra Text Displaying in My jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, free-jqgrid

When my colModel contains a hyperlink I get extra text on the grid. Text seams to appear after the grid definition and before the pager container.

This is what display on the grid(Test is the link):
Test 
Test' tabindex='-1' class='ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr'>

Comment: I finally figured out that the link should no be in 'ID' column. When I moved it to second column all is well.